# Send HTTP Request TO iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an app where the iPhone sends data to a server and the server manipulates that data. I need a way of getting the manipulated data back to the iPhone. How can the iPhone know when the data is done being manipulated and how does it get it back?

I've been looking for ways to do this with NSURLConnection but I have had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you'd like to use HTTP for this, you would probably have the iPhone poll the server (periodically or upon user request) with some sort of ID, and the server would return an appropriate response (either the processed data or some sort of "still processing" message). The URL might look like: http://myserver/data_processing_thingy?id=some_unique_id

NSURLConnection is quite simple to use for HTTP GET requests, simply Google or StackOverflow it.

Comment: `[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:self]` will get you going, it'll call back when it's done - implement the needed delegate methods of [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that you need (response/data/etc.)

Comment: server needs to churn on the data and output it to a format you can parse when you get it back XML/json/etc.

Comment: yea I ended up just putting the data into a text file when it was done being processed and the app is continually polling the text file until there is something there.